Sql batching in sql alchemy
I need to execute many insertion and update statements, and I want to batch them to reduce db roundtrips.
Our application accesses db through SQL Alchemy, but we do not use its ORM. Instead we always use session.execute to run SQL.
Seems unit of work system is able to do what I want but it requires ORM.
I wonder what’s the best way to batch executing SQL statements without ORM.
